# Как нанести множество маршрутов и иметь возможность удалять выборочно маршрут?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, карты

Использую `google.map.api`. На карту добавляю несколько маршрутов. Есть ли возможность удалить один из них по клику на кнопку. Выглядит это так: [код в песочнице](https://jsfiddle.net/kuzya/224u70an/5/)

```
var map, directionsService;
var directions= [];

function renderDirections(result, index, polylineOpts) {
    /* var rendererOptions = {
            suppressPolylines: true,
            map: map              
        } */
  var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); //rendererOptions

  directions[index]=directionsRenderer;

  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

  if (polylineOpts) {
    directionsRenderer.setOptions({
      polylineOptions: polylineOpts
    });
  }

  directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
}

function requestDirections(start, end, index, polylineOpts) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(result) {
    renderDirections(result, index, polylineOpts);
  });
}

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47, 39),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  requestDirections('Rostov', "Novorossiysk", 0, {
    strokeColor: 'red'
  });
  requestDirections('Krasnodar', "Anapa", 1, {
    strokeColor: '#0FA099'
  });
  requestDirections('Кореновск', "Тамань", 2, {
    strokeColor: 'yellow'
  });

console.log(directions);
//directions[1].setMap(null);

/*   setTimeout(function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
  }, 2000); */

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var delBtn = document.querySelector('#delete');

delBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  directions[1].directions.request.travelMode = "TRANSIT";
  delete directions[0].clearDirections();
  console.log(directions);
})
```

Comment: В stackoverflow есть встроенная песочница. Пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь ей и не помещайте код на сторонние сервисы вроде jsfiddle. Весь код должен находиться прямо в тексте вопроса без каких-либо ссылок

Comment: Задаю вопрос впервые.Не нашла, как изменить свой вопрос...

Comment: Кнопочка [«править»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/769341/edit) под его текстом

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить для маршрута `null` в качестве карты:

```
directions[0].setMap(null);
```